# saving lists as elements of matrix

Tags: r, list, matrix

I am trying to add lists as an element of matrix. I am using the following code

```
wiip <- matrix(list(), 5, 5)
for (i in colnames(wave1)) {
    for (j in colnames(wave1)) {
        wiip[[i,j]] <- gclo(wave1[[i]], wave1[[j]])
    }
}
```

the `wiip[[i,j]]` says subscripts out of bounds.
the output from the function gclo is a list and I want to save all the outputs. that is the double loop creates i*j(i runs over 1 to 5 and so does j, hence total 25 lists objects are created) number of lists. how to save each list together in one object.

Comment: Did you mean to repeat `colnames(wave1)` for both `i` and `j`? Also, you are indexing names in `wiip` when it doesn't have names.

Comment: `rownames(wiip) <- colnames(wiip) <- colnames(wave1)`

Comment: What is `wave1` ? A dataframe or matrix ? Which package is `gclo` function from?

Comment: @thelatemail yes i am repeting for both i and j. I did not get the second part of your comment. when I did it for 1D that is `wiip<-vector('lists')` it does without any probelm.

Comment: @RonakShah wave1 is a matrix. gclo is a self defined function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to save the result in a list and use `[, i]` and `[,j]` to subset each column of the matrix.

```
wiip <- vector('list', ncol(wave1)*ncol(wave1))
ind <- 0

for (i in colnames(wave1)) {
  for (j in colnames(wave1)) {
    ind <- ind + 1
    wiip[[ind]] <- gclo(wave1[, i], wave1[, j])
  }
}
```

Comment: this thing did run. But the output didnt have any proper indexing. this was mainly because when I put `colnames(wave1)*colnames(wave1)` in the first part of your code. it showed an error "non-numeric argument to binary operator". then I had to put the number of rows and columns, i.e. 5 and 5, instead of colnames. any help regarding this. because the ouput dees have 25 objects but I cant figure out which is using what combinations of columns.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. That should be `ncol` instead of `colnames`.

Comment: is there any way so that i can name the objects of wiip based on combination of columns it used to generate?

Comment: @utkarshkumar You can use - `names(wiip) <- c(outer(colnames(wave1), colnames(wave1), Vectorize(function(x, y) paste0(x, y, collapse = '|'))))`